# How to visualize geocoordinates by dots with python

Tags: python, coordinates, visualization, draw

I have a whole bunch of geocoordinates (around 125000 from all over the world)  which I want to visualize in a coordinate system (for printing later). Which is the easiest way to go?

Answer (score 3):

For simple lon/lat [x/y] dots, the matplotlib does the job. If you need to have some simple map in the background (such as continent boundaries, major cities, rivers) or use a specific projection, check [matplotlib.toolkits.basemap.basemap](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/matplotlib.toolkits.basemap.basemap.html).